# Table doesn't / does exist in engine

Tags: windows, mariadb, heidisql

Lot's of threads, but couldn't find one that fits.  I am new at all this.

I had to downgrade from MariaDB 10.11 to 10.6 on Windows for reasons with IIS.  So just uninstalled 10.11 and started with new Data folder.  Copied in some small tables with a tool.  For larger tables I ran a script in HeidiSQL to create the table structures.  No errors, but the tables did not show. Refreshed and restarted HeidiSQL.  Tried to re-create one of the tables in HeidiSQL and I am told it already exists.  Try to drop that table at command line, and told it does not exist.  The tables do not exist in the Data folder.

I am at a point where I can delete the whole database and start from scratch, but I would like to know how to prevent this in the future.

[exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptUl8.png)
[not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHO0F.png)

Bill.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the database and recreated it.  Still got the error saying tables existed.  Ultimately I uninstalled MariaDB, reinstalled, and walked through adding the tables successfully.

I'd still like to know what the issue was, but at least I am moving again.

Bill.